# When I click on item not showing alertdialouge?

Tags: android

I want to display alert dialogue on click of pdfimage, I try following code but not showing alertdialogue .

```
private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener=new OnItemClickListener() {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
      int i=position;
      pdf=pdfarray[i];
 /*******************************/
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageShowActivity.this);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setNeutralButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            alert.dismiss();   
           }
        })
       .setPositiveButton("Download", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           Intent intent=new Intent(ImageShowActivity.this,OpenPDFNew.class);
           intent.putExtra("pdfurl",pdf );
           startActivity(intent);
           }
       })
      .setNegativeButton("Online", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           }
   });
    alert.show();
/****************************************/
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `builder.create()` before declaring the contents of alert Builder, you should call `builder.create()` after creating the contents like this,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_name.this);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                .........
                }
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change in your code and remove `final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();`

also at `alert.show();`

replace with

```
builder.create().show();
```